# How to create a tube 2D in unity

Tags: unity, c#

I want to create a 2D tube in unity which I can cut, suture and drag it,  My idea is to use a small image in form of fragments but how i can do it like the picture bellow

[image]

EDIT : 
What I did until now:

Firstly I tried to use Linerenderer but it didn't work for me because i couldn't cut it so tried to create a tube of cubes I used an empty object as parent whit childs of cubes as you can see on the picture bellow

[image]

with this way it was easy to apply the cut script so I just remove the fixed joint between the cubes where i click 
and for the appearance of the tube I started by creating it as a direct line and I turned on the game then by dragging the tube i get the form bellow and i copy the position of each cube and set it on the instantiation of the childs

```
   GameObject intestines_top = GameObject.Find("intestine_top");

    setPositions();//on this method I instantiate an array of vector3 contains all the position i get 
    fragments = new GameObject[fragmentNum];


    Vector3 position = Vector3.zero;

    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentNum; i++)
    {
        fragments[i] = Instantiate(fragmentPrefab, positionArray[i], Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0.413f, -259.96f, -536.531f)));
        fragments[i].transform.SetParent(transform);


        var joint = fragments[i].GetComponent<FixedJoint>();

        joint.connectedBody = parent.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        parent = fragments[i];

    }
```

the result of what i did : 
[image]

**NOTE :**  other problem of my solution is sometimes all the gameobjects disperss due to collision I think 
That's happen after a while of dragging the tube
I didn't find what exactly the problem but when I change the direction of the collider to the X-axis its solve the problem by 85% and for the drag script i use AddForce and velocity

`rigid.AddForce((dest - rigid.position) * 200f); rigid.velocity *= 0.8f;`
[image]

Comment: What prevented you from taking the points from one LineRenderer and making two LineRenderers, each with the points on one side of the cut, or vice-versa?

Comment: What do you mean with "all the gameobjects disperss due to collision"? Does your screenshot show that effect? What situation causes it to happen?

Comment: I added a screen for this, it(s happen after a while of dragging

Comment: Ah, the plot thickens. Have you done some research about why exactly this physics glitch happens? And how exactly did you implement the "dragging"? Did you use AddForce or do you change the position? Because the latter is known to cause weird physics glitches. The more your rely on the physics engine, the more critical it becomes that you supply it with accurate input, which means to move all objects with forces.

Comment: What's the point of `rigid.velocity *= 0.8f;`? You generally shouldn't change the velocity of a rigidbody when you do a complicated physics system. If you want the object to have some friction, increase the drag of the rigidbody in the inspector.

Comment: I commented it and it didn't shows any different so I removed it ... well if we can come back to our main question which is how to create the tube like the first picture i don